# Definition of invariant composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Context**:

My class notes say:

> It may happen that a finite group (even a solvable one) does not have an **invariant composition series**.
>
> In other words, if you have a **composition series** (this time with ascending numbering)
>
> $$1 < H_1 < H_2 < ... < H_n = G$$
>
> one way for it to be **favorable** is for $H_i$ to be normal in all of $G$ rather than just normal in $H_{k+1}$.  Another way for it to favorable is for the quotients $H_{i+1}/H_i$ to be simple.

**Questions**:

1. A composition series [*by definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#For_groups) has simple factors $H_{i+1}/H_{i}$. So is every *composition series* an *invariant composition series*?
2. Is the statement "every $H_i$ is normal in all of $G$" equivalent to the statement "every quotient $H_{i+1}/H_{i}$ is simple"? Or is it a typo and the author actually meant "every quotient $H_{i+1}/H_{i}$ is abelian"?
3. Is a group having an invariant composition series automatically *solvable*?

Comment: It seems like the intended message was something like this. consider a normal series: one way for it to be good is if it is an invariant series. A different way to be good is for it to be a composition series. Neither of these implies the other, they are just two different flavors of normal series to study.  Invariant composition series is both at the same time, and would be “very good”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. $A_4$ has a composition series which is not invariant. But here I think the author simply says that the situation when a composition series is invariant is simply better then the other way around.
2. $H_{i+1}/H_i$ already are simple, that doesn't make much sense (unless the author meant "subnormal series" instead of "composition series"). And no, if $H_i$ are normal in all of $G$, then it doesn't imply that every quotient is abelian. Any non-abelian simple group is an example. Anyway, I think it should be "the quotients to be abelian", and the author simply claims that such situation is desirable.
3. No. Again, any non-abelian simple group is a counterexample.

Comment: So what conditions (if any) on the quotients would ensure that $H_i$ is normal in all of $G$?

Comment: @Triskelion I don't think there are any known, except for some trivial ones (like $G$ being abelian or hamiltonian).

Comment: Thanks! And in point 2 of your answer did you actually mean: "if $H_i$ are normal **in all of $G$** it doesn't imply every quotient is abelian"? And does the implication not hold the other way round either?

Comment: @Triskelion I've updated the answer. And no, the other way around is not true as well. $A_4$ is also solvable.

Comment: Thanks again! I've just another minor confusion. You used the term "desirable" in point 2. Quotients being abelian is desirable for *what* (considering abelian quotients don't ensure invariance of composition series)?

Comment: @Triskelion for further mathematics. :) Solvable groups have applications in many different areas.